# Prevent downloading a file in Spring Boot api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to avoid downloading a file by user as Internet Download Manager can download all types of files automatically, how to avoid this to secure my media content.
I am making a API in Spring Boot to stream videos(not live stream).

How to achieve this?

Comment: Cannot be done, since there is no difference between a "download" and a "view", as far as the server can see. Presenting web content requires the browser to "download" the content to its cache, so if you prevent "downloading", the browser cannot get the content to display it.

Comment: https://courses.edutap.co.in/learn
This website has this type of implementation, we cannot download paid courses. Only a few files that are on trial basis are downloadable, but others are not

Comment: So you're not actually asking about preventing "download", but about restricting "access", i.e. **securing** the webapp, so that only users who have paid for a particular item can access it? Which means that the user needs to be logged in, so you know who the user is?

Comment: Yes, but only can play video files and cannot download that content

Comment: @LakshyaveerChaudhary once you find the solution, keep it secret and sell it to the highest bidder. The end of piracy will be in sight!

Comment: Hahaha.........\

Comment: Even if they can't download it they can still probably record their screen while playing the video I guess...

Comment: @IvanDimitrov, Yes very true